# How to start a script when Déjà Dup starts or an SMB share was mounted?

Tags: 13.04, scripts, backup, deja-dup

I need to start a script when a deja-dup backup starts. When deja-dup starts the backup, a SMB share is mounted by deja-dup. So, would it also be possible to start the script after this SMB share was mounted?

Is there a way to do that?

I have Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the target share was mounted (see bellow) and then run your script.

```bsh
if grep -qs '/mnt/target_smb_share' /proc/mounts; then
    run_your_script_here
fi
```

Comment: In your approach I have to frequently check if the share was mounted. I would prefer that the execution of the script is triggert by the mount process.

Comment: It could be added as a cron job to check periodically for the share in the question every x minutes or hours.